# How can I add "Add user link" when the username is not in the database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to display the link "Add as User" in my view only when the username is not in the database. I have a method called UsernameExists in my SQL data access layer that I would like to use in the AccountController. How would I go about doing that? The logic should be on the server side, and the link shown on the view.

Comment: you should probably add some detail to this question.  are you asking that it be shown conditionally client side, or server side?

Comment: i think the logic should be on the server side, but the link has to be shown in the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the UsernameExists method from your controller and add the result to the ViewBag. In your view check the ViewBag and if the bool is true (the username already exists) then don't display the "Add as User" else display it.

Example-

Controller:

```
ViewBag.usernameExists = model.UsernameExists(username);
```

View:

```
@if(!(bool)ViewBag.usernameExists)
{
    <a>Add as User</a>
    //Whatever you want to display
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I access the UsernameExists method from the controller if it's in another class (SQLContactDAL) in another library (SQLContactLibrary)?

Comment: @multiv123 Add a reference to SQLContactLibrary in your project. Then if it is a static method: SQLContactLibrary.SQLContactDAL.UsernameExists(username); //this may vary slightly depending on the class namespace.

Comment: There already is a reference to SqlContactLibrary in References. I put the ViewBag statement in the action method public ActionResult CreateUser.

Comment: whats the problem? Can you post your code you can't get to work? Your last message didn't report a problem.

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work...ViewBag.usernameExists = model.SqlContactLibrary.SQLContactDAL.UsernameExists(model.UserName); i think i'm missing a using directive for SqlContactLibrary either in this controller file or in the simpleuser file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5568/discussion-between-multiv123-and-xbrady)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like using remote validation is what you would want to do, then you would show the hidden link on the page. You get this almost for free with MVC, then  you would do some client side script to show/hide the link. 
ViewModel:

```
public CreateUserVM
{
    [Required]
    [Remote("UsernameExists","YourController")]
    string Username { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model CreateUserVM
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username, "Enter User Name:")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult UsernameExists(CreateUserVM user)
{
  //logic to check if user name exists
}
```